# The type 'Memory<T>' exists in both 'System.Memory 4.0.1.0 and mscorlib 2.0.5.0

Tags: xamarin.ios

i'm having hard time resolving this new issue.
It appears only on the xamarin.ios project of the solution at compile time.
The xamarin.android project is compiling ok.

I did not reference system.memory but netstandard 2.0 projects.
That was compiling fine until recently.

Is it a known issue in xamarin.ios tooling ? any workaround ?

I've tried:

- googling
- add the system.memory nuget to the ios project
- delete bin/obj/.vs folders, clean/rebuild

I'm dry.

Comment: Are you sure that your project's `.NetStandard` library does not have this?

Comment: system.memory is included in netstandard. So it comes from netstandard.

Comment: Yeah, so do you need it is the point! In the `.Net Standard`

Comment: "do you need it is the point" => yes otherwise i would not have any problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution [here](https://jaylee.org/archive/2019/03/31/using-span-of-t-in-xamarin-cross-targeted-projects.html) !

Add at the end of your ios project file:

```cs
  <Target 
    Name="VS16_RemoveSystemMemory" 
    BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences" 
    Condition="'$(MSBuildVersion)' &gt;= '16.0'">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_ReferencePathToRemove 
        Include="@(ReferencePath)" 
        Condition="'%(ReferencePath.NuGetPackageId)'=='System.Memory'" />
      <ReferencePath Remove="@(_ReferencePathToRemove)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Removing System.Memory for VS 2019 compatibility" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
```

And magically it compiles !
I don't know from where this nuget dependency came, but it's not from my code, it's from a third party nuget, most probably from the Google ones.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that arrives here on a related issue around `Span<T>` or `ReadOnlySpan<T>` being ambiguous in Xamarin iOS with .NET Standard 2.1 dependencies, the issue is still related to `System.Memory` but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58447541/641995) pointed out by Softlion did not solve for me. The reasoning and workaround pointed out in this [thread][2] was my underlying problem:

> There are two types of the same name `System.ReadOnlySpan` in the app declared and cannot be unified.
>
> The first one is declared in System.Memory.dll (one implementation)
>
> The second one is in netstandard.dll (the type-forwarder to the second implementation inside mscorlib.dll)
>
> The bug is in System.Memory nuget because it's missing netstandard2.1 TFM implementation where the `System.ReadOnlySpan` type would not be declared in the assembly but referenced from netstandard.dll

Adding package references for System.Memory 4.5.4 and System.Buffers 4.5.1 was the workaround I needed.

Comment: does not work for me